# Best practice for starting a job on a remote server with another job

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job

My apologies if this is not the right place to be asking. I've had posts marked in the past as unrelated because I was asking for opinions, and I think this might be borderline?

I want to be able to run a job on a remote SQL server from a job on another SQL server. I know how to do this, that is not my question.

We recently migrated our servers at work, and redid all of the security/permissions/logins for pretty much everything. So now were on a security craze. Previously I was able to perform this action by using a linkserver and just using the command

```
EXEC [LINKSERVER].msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'JOB NAME'
```

But since the migration, the linkserver I used to use to do this, is now gone, and they are not entertaining my request to set it back up. They said to use a different method that is being used in another job.

So I found that job, and it's using SQLCMD, which requires storing the Username and Password in the job step. Using this code:

```
declare @cmd varchar(2000), @Success int
set @cmd='sqlcmd -S "{IP ADDRESS}" -U {USERNAME} -P {PASSSWORD} -Q "exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name=''JOB NAME''"'
exec @Success = xp_cmdshell @cmd
IF (@Success = 0)
   PRINT 'Success'
ELSE
   PRINT 'Failure';
```

In my opinion, that seems much less secure than using a link server? No? Because now anyone and their mother that has at least read access to those job steps can grab that login, which has limited access, but still. If for some reason that user had their SQL privileges revoked, or left the company, they would still have some way of logging into the SQL server.

Storing credentials in clear text just about anywhere has always been a red flag to me. From a security stand point, what's the best way to accomplish this task?

Comment: You could delve into SSIS which would allow you to connect to any number of servers and execute stored procedures while obfuscating credentials - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141003.aspx.

Comment: @Anand and that would be more secure / better practice than just setting up a linked server?

Comment: Not necessarily a better solution as much as an equally good option if linked server is not an option. A linked server is an easy method for simple jobs; SSIS is more elaborate and offers a lot of features.

Comment: I'd say fight to get the linked server back, or have the DBAs detail what "different method" they would recommend. Maybe they're just saying no out of principle. But IMHO if they're going to say "no you can't do what you were doing before" they kind of need to tell you what the alternative is.

Comment: You could go any number of directions here. I've had service broker on the mind recently and you could do something there by sending a message to a queue on the remote server where something would pick it up and start the job for you.

Comment: I finally got them to set up a linkserver for me. I overwhelmed the Sr DBA with issues and questions, so they finally set it up. And now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is to use `OPENROWSET` as described [this article](http://www.theboreddba.com/Categories/miscellaneous/Using-OPENROWSET-instead-of-a-Linked-Server.aspx). Use the dynamic query approach at the bottom.